# Spring security: set-cookie doesn't work in non-spring environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spinrg boot app where my frontend code is placed inside the `static folder`, and everything works great there.

I develop my frontend source outside my spring project and build it to the static folder.

When I run my spring boot app, the frontend works great and the login stores a cookie named `JSESSIONID` then my API requests work.

The problem is that when I develop my frontend I'm serving my client outside of spring, and the cookie is not stored in my browser upon a successful login.

**The question:**
Any idea how I can solve it- access and store the cookie although the client is not served with spring?

My spring httpsecurity config:

```
http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**" , "/assets/**" , "/api/information").permitAll() 
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .failureHandler(failureHandler())
//              .failureUrl("/authentication/login-error.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                  .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
//              .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                .and()
                  .logout() 
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();
```

Set cookie received from spring:

set-cookie:JSESSIONID=1F16D001A85DDD17CE840CF2A3694231;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly

Comment: So, you're getting the "set-cookie" header, but your browser is not sending it along with requests?

Comment: No, my browser do not stores the cookie at all

Comment: Can you tell more about your developing mode? Since you're serving your client outside, you should facing cross-domain issues (ports mismatch at least). How did you solve it? CORS filter? Some special browser settings? Also, your cookie marked with `Secure` flag, R U using https?